# Probability of Drawing from a Specific Group N Number of Times

Tags: probability, statistics

It is entirely possible this question has been asked, but I am not finding it based on the queries I am entering into the search bar. Therefore, if this has already been answered, a direction to the question is most helpful.

I have three groups each with a different number of participants.

Group A has 14 participants

Group B has 9 participants

Group C has 7 participants

What I am trying to figure out is the probability of group A getting drawn n = 1, 2, ..., 7 times given that I am drawing from the entire 30 participant population at random without replacement. In the end, I should have a total of 7 probabilities.

It has been a long time since I have done any of this, so a refresher is most helpful.

Thank you in advance. Please ask if you have further questions.

Comment: P1 = 14/(14+9+7), P2 = 13/(13+9+7), ... Assuming without replacement.

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  Are you asking, e.g., "If we draw $n$ people without replacement, what is the probability that all $n$ are from $A$?" or are you asking "given that we draw $7$ people without replacement, what is the probability that exactly $1$ was in $A$?  Exactly $2$?  and so on."

Comment: $0$ is a possibility if you draw $16$ or fewer times

Comment: Given that we draw 7 people, what is the probability that we draw one person from A. Then a totally new equation, where we now are drawing two from A without replacement. This is then followed by 3 from a without replacement all the way to all 7 in the study are from A without replacement. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of drawing $k = 0, 1, \dots, 7$ from among the $14$ in Group A given that I choose without replacement from among the $30.$ Let $X$ be the random result.

$$P(X = k) = \frac{{14 \choose k}{16\choose 7-k}}{{30\choose 7}}.$$

For example, for $k = 2$ the result is $P(X = 2) = 0.195249.$ In R:

```
choose(14,2)*choose(16,5)/choose(30, 7)
[1] 0.195249
```

Or, you can evaluate the factorials: ${a\choose b} = \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!},$ for integers $a\ge 0, b\ge 0, a\ge b,$ with $0!=1.$

This is a ***hypergeometric*** distribution. In R, the distribution table can be
computed as below: (Ignore row numbers in brackets `[ ]`.)

```
k = 0:7;  pdf = dhyper(k, 14,16, 7)
cbind(k, pdf)

     k         pdf
[1,] 0 0.005619413
[2,] 1 0.055070243
[3,] 2 0.195249042
[4,] 3 0.325415070
[5,] 4 0.275351213
[6,] 5 0.118007663
[7,] 6 0.023601533
[8,] 7 0.001685824
```

As @Henry has commented, $P(X = 0)$ is positive when drawing $7 < 16$ items,
but you can ignore that probability if it is somehow not of interest.